# Multivariate normality assumption of SEMs

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, multivariate-normal-distribution

I am calculating structural equation models as part of my thesis and am currently in the process of checking the assumptions. One assumption is multivariate normal distribution. This applies to all variables in the model, i.e. dependent, independent and covariates, right?

I am checking the assumptions using `SPSS` and have the gray matter of two brain regions as independent variables, but the data is divided into quite a few sub-brain regions (and for the right and left hemispheres), which is why I have about 100-200 variables in my data set.

I'm a bit unsure how to proceed now. I have read that multivariate normal distribution is given if the maximum Mahalanobis distances is lower than the critical value or (on another site) if the mean of the squared Mahalanobis distances (Mardia’s coefficient) is lower than the critical value. Next, I could see if the distribution changes when I remove outliers or transform the data.

**But for that I would have to aggregate all my (100-200) variables to two independent variables first, right?**

Comment: It might be important to know why you need SEM in the first place. Do you have a model you are envisioning here that necessitates it's usage? Your question doesn't right away indicate it's utility in answering your research question.

Answer (score 2):

"But for that I would have to aggregate all my (100-200) variables to two independent variables first, right?" I don't understand why this might be the case, but I think the answer is no.

Depending on your sample size, if your data are not normally distributed you can use weighted least squares (or some flavor: WLSMV, DWLS) or the Satorra-Bentler scaled chi-square. You can also bootstrap your parameter estimates.

If you have 100-200 predictor variables, I think you might have other problems though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't have that many predictor variables; my two predictor variables (brain region A and B) were previously partialized into many small brain regions (i.e. brain regions A1, A2, A3, ...; B1, B2, B3, ...). Since I am not interested in these small brain regions, but only in the brain regions A and B, I would have to aggregate the data first/before checking the assumptions, right?

Comment: I don't quite understand. You check the assumptions of the data that you're analyzing.  Are you doing that aggregation before you do the analysis? I think so, which means you have two predictors.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!